# Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component was successfully initialized, but server failed to start

Tags: neo4j

I was given a graph db I must open with Neo4j. Installed community version Neo4j-2.2.0-M02 on Win7 Ultimate laptop successfully. When I tried to start the server, after pointing to the graph db, I get the following error:

> Starting Neo4j Server failed:
>   Component `org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@325ce05c` was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

Logged in as windows local admin. Windows FWall is off. There's no antivirus SW installed on the machine. Local admin has full perms on entire root drive. When I point to the default db, Neo4j server starts normally and I can browse http://localhost:7474/ without a problem.

Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what the log says, located in C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community\logs

Comment: particulary messages.log

Comment: Hello Christophe,  How can I share the log w/o violating any of the formatting rules of this web site? I tried to attach an image to save text space but I'm not old enough (get a warning msg to that respect) on this  web site to do so. I have no google+, twitter nor facebook accnt only gmail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The aforementioned error message was the result of using a Neo4j version different to the one the graph db was originally developed. In particular, the original graph db was developed in ver 2.0.4 Community that due to my lack of knowledge I was trying to run on an installation of Neo4j ver. 2.2.0-M02 (for development only). 
The code owner enlightened me to the fact and an attempt to bring up the graph db on ver. 2.0.4 Community was successful.
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the folder  "c:\Users\Yourname\MyDocuments\Neo4j"

Answer (score 1):

I removed the plugins that were loaded from `<NEO4J_HOME>/plugins` as they were also loaded from under `<DATABASE_HOME>/plugins`