# issue with importing the graph database (developed in Neo4j windows environment) in Mac environment

Tags: macos, neo4j

I'm new to neo4j and have been trying to figure out how to import a graph database to my neo4j server.

Installation and running neo4j were ok on my Mac (version 2.3.1). However, when I changed the database location from the default one to the actual database I want to import, neo4j refused to do so.

I've checked this forum with the error message, and thought that this might be due to the version incompatibility issue (see thread [Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component was successfully initialized, but server failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018153/starting-neo4j-server-failed-component-was-successfully-initialized-but-server)). But after I installed the earlier version and tried it, it was still not working.

I begin to wonder if it's due to the fact that the database was developed in Windows, and I am in Mac environment. If you were able to successfully migrate the data between the two OS using neo4j, could you drop a note here? Thank you!

**Update:** I followed the first suggestion and was able to have the server point to the correct database. But Cypher query did not return anything. [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5dZf.png). See my detailed comment below. Your help is greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: @MicTech I followed your suggestion and the server now points to the imported database location. thanks!But a Cypher MATCH query returned 0 row -- the same query was able to return the nodes and relationships on the same graph database in the developer's Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set upgrading store to true

**conf/neo4j.properties**

```
allow_store_upgrade=true
```